# Dynamic Fields at content type level

Tags: views, 8, entities, taxonomy-terms

I got a site where we got pages tagged with several taxonomy terms. We also got several Contactblocks (added as Content Type & displayed by Views) that are tagged with the same set of taxonomy terms.

The Content Type "Contactblock" has the fields E-Mail, Phone & Room. Those Fields may vary from page to page. The reason behind this is some employees have different positions and those have to be displayed on different pages with different information. May way to go atm was to add multiple Contactblocks but its not clean enough for me.

My idea was to display for each tagged term a specific field of E-Mail, Phone & Room. But idk how the system can associate it then..

Atm its like ***page<->taxonomy term<->contactblock*** but it should be like ***page<->taxonomy term, for each tax term<->create fields: mail, phone & room***

Any idea how I can solve this? Any better idea is apreciated

Comment: You could do **page<->contactBlock** will that work for you? or do you really need those tax term tags?

Comment: how woud this improve my situation @NoSssweat ?

Comment: no need to fill the Database with tax terms, I guess.

Comment: `it should be like page<->taxonomy term<->contactblock<->for each tax term<->create fields: mail, phone & room` I think you mean **page<->taxonomy term, for each tax term<->create fields: mail, phone & room** cause no point in creating the mail, phone & room fields in the tax terms and also in the Contactblock.

Comment: I use the tax terms to associate contactblocks of employees to several fields that they work at..

Comment: @NoSssweat yes right!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add fields: mail, phone & room to each of your tax terms, but the problem would be that all your employees would have the same mail, phone & room, because the fields belong to the tax term and not the employee. Unless you create a unique tax term for each of your employees this would work, but why do this when **page<->contactBlock** will do the same?

So either you stick with **page<->taxonomy term<->contactblock**

or go with **page<->contactBlock** using the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module in D7 (for D8 Drupal Core already has this module's features). This option will save you save Database space since you don't create tax terms.

Comment: I'm I right that I have to still add multiple contactblocks for every page and every position the employee works at?

Comment: For each employee you need to create a contact block for them. I assume in the employee profile you have a field for his position. `some employees have different positions and have to be displayed on different pages` You can then use views to filter employees by position and show only employees with position "X".

Comment: right and the positions are my tax terms. How should I filter them if I remove the taxonomy from the relation?

Comment: Also that wouldn't solve the fact that I still have to add multiple Contactblocks that contain the different mail, phone etc...

Comment: `How should I filter them if I remove the taxonomy from the relation?` You can add a Contextual Filter with a default fixed value of the employee position.

Comment: @SaifDeen One thing that wasn't clear to me, where are you adding the employee name and last name? Are you creating drupal users for each employee? or did you create a content type where you add each employee? or does the ContactBlock also contain the employee name and lastname fields?

Comment: I have a content type that has all the necessary fields....